# Show that the closure of a connected set is connected.

Tags: proof-verification, connectedness

> Show that if $A$ is a connected subset of a metric space $X$, then $\overline{A}$ is connected.

My approach: If $A$ is a connected subset of metric space $X$, then $\emptyset$ and $A$ are open and closed.

If $A=A^{\circ}$, then $A$ is open and if $A=\overline{A}$, then $A$ is closed. So,

$$A^{\circ}=\overline{A}^{\circ}\subset \overline{A}$$
$$\overline{A}=A\subset\overline{A}=A^{\circ}=\overline{A}^{\circ}\implies \overline{A}\subset\overline{A}^{\circ}$$

Then $\overline{A}=\overline{A}^{\circ}=A^{\circ}$, then $\overline{A}$ is open. And clearly, $\overline{A}$ is closed. So $\overline{A}$ is closed.
This is correct?? Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is connected $\bf{\text{only}}$ $A$ and $\emptyset$ are open and closed.

Comment: you could try this approach: supposing $A$ connected, let $\bar{A}$ = $A \cup A'$ ; $A'$ is limit points of $A$ in $X$. now for a contradiction, suppose $\bar{A}$ = $B \cup C$ ; where $C,B$ are both nonempty, disjoint,open, closed, in $X$ (def of NOT being connected) and neither is all of $\bar{A}$, hint, connected implies you HAVE to be in one or the other (if $A = B \cup C$,  $A$, WLOG, is in $B$), this is the idea of the proof, you use the fact that you include limit points which forces your open sets to also be in the same ($B$ WLOG) clopen set that $A$ is FORCED to be in by its assumption

Answer (score 2):

You have the definition of connected wrong.  $A$ is connected iff its only clopen subsets (when it is considered a subspace) are itself and $\emptyset$.

Suppose $\bar A$ is not connected.   Then there is nonempty, clopen (in $\bar A$) $B$ with $B\subsetneq\bar A$.

Then consider $C=B\cap A$.

Claim: $C\subsetneq A$ is nonempty and clopen in $A$.

$C$ is nonempty because $B\subset\bar A$ is open.

$C$ is clopen in $A$ because $B=U\cap \bar A$, where $U$ is clopen in $X$ (thus $C=U\cap A$).